# Mapboxの衛星画像（satellite image）の更新頻度について

Tags: mapbox

Mapboxの衛星画像（satellite image）の撮影年月や更新頻度が知りたい。
どなたかご存知の方、ご教授頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: mapboxが公開してなかったら知りようが無い気がしますが...mapboxのsiteには記載されてませんか？他のsiteに書いてあってもそれが保証されるわけではないので、mapboxが公開してなくて、どうしても必要ならmapboxに問い合わせるしか無いと思いますが。

Comment: サイト上で記載を確認することができず、もしわかればと思い質問させて頂きました。mapboxに問合せしてみます。

Comment: mapboxから回答もらえたら、その内容を差し障りのない範囲で回答に記述してもらえたら良いと思います。もし、非公開ですって回答であったとしても、非公開って事が分かるなら有益な情報だと思います。